# Terminal (any one) losing lines after scrolling back on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, ruby-on-rails

I am having some troubles with Ubuntu 22.04 on an Acer Nitro 5 core i7, specially one annoying is that I cannot have a reliable scroll back listing because the terminal simply loses some lines, cutting the sequence and delivering simply gibberish, you can see in the attached image that there are several missing lines in the scrool back sequence... I have tried with several terminal apps, all of them have the same result, I have already changed the scroll back limit to no limit or a big number like 500000 lines but any time the output is cut. Please help, this is annoying and limiting my productivity as a programer.
[image: Lost lines]

Edit: Apparently the problem happens when I use Ruby on Rails console (irb)

Comment: Are you just using a shell inside the terminal, or are you invoking some kind of CLI or TUI application (looks like maybe a database client?)

Comment: @steeldriver, I'm using Rails console with Ruby 'irb'

Comment: Another very similar report, making me suspect it might be a weird bug in `irb`: https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/issues/1979

Comment: The issue turned out to be a less than ideal behavior of some terminal emulators, combined with a less than ideal behavior of `irb`. Konsole (shown in the screenshot) fixed it on Jan 27, 2022 in their development series. In VTE (used by GNOME Terminal and many other frontends) the fix landed today in the development series, to be released in stable version 0.76.0 in March 2024. Some other terminals (e.g. Windows Terminal) reportedly still suffers from this issue.